# Errors when downloading files from Azure Blob Storage from ASP.net C# website

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, httpresponse

I am trying to download files from Azure blob storage to my website then out to the persons browser who initiated the download but I receive errors sometimes. So far I have received the following Errors:

1. OutputStream is not available when a custom TextWriter is used.
2. Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent.
3. Server cannot modify cookies after HTTP headers have been sent.

I have tried several things the first attempt was this:

```
var account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(Properties.Settings.Default.AzureConnectionString);
            var blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(Properties.Settings.Default.AzureContainer);
            var blob = container.GetBlobReference(path);
            if (blob.Exists())
            {
                MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
                blob.DownloadToStream(memStream);
                httpCurrentContext.Response.ContentType = mimeType;
                httpCurrentContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "Attachment; filename=" + name.ToString());
                httpCurrentContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", blob.Properties.Length.ToString());
                httpCurrentContext.Response.BinaryWrite(memStream.ToArray());
                httpCurrentContext.Response.Flush();
                httpCurrentContext.Response.End();
             }
```

The second attempt was to replace the BinaryWrite with this:

```
                httpCurrentContext.Response.BufferOutput = true;
                httpCurrentContext.Response.OutputStream.Write(memStream.ToArray(), 0, (int)blob.Properties.Length);
```

Both randomly throw errors but sometimes they work.

Comment: Randomly throws what errors?

Comment: But, why do you want to download to the website and then send it to the browser?  Seems like an unnecessary step. Why don't you make the container public and put the link to your site? You can even configure your custom domain for the storage. Or if you don't want to make the container public you can just get a SAS token for your storage.

Comment: I am storing all of the blobs as encrypted files and they have to be decrypted via the website prior to download. It is an SOP for the company. 

The random errors are in the list above and each one is thrown on different download events. The errors all happen on either OutputStream.Write or BinaryWrite.